# Unique combination of columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, combinations

I have a table that calculates the similarity between two users; e.g.

```
user1   user2    similarity
  1       3          0.7
  2       1          0.9
 ...     ...         ...
 ...     ...         ...
 ...     ...         ...
```

What I need is to model the table so that once you have that model above, the following insert:

```
replace into table values(3,1,0.4)
```

will actually update the first row. Is there a standard practice for this type of situation? This is, the combination of user1 and user2 has to be unique e.g.: (3,1) should be considered the same as (1,3).

Comment: You can try to create a BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE trigger which swaps the values of user1 and user2 when user1 > user2, but I don't know what will happen when there are UNIQUE constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to resort to a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertOrUpdateSimilarity (
    pu1 INT, pu2 INT, ps FLOAT -- user1, user2, similarity
)
BEGIN
    -- try to update either (pu1, pu2) or (pu2, pu1)
    UPDATE similarities SET similarity = ps
    WHERE (user1 = pu1 AND user2 = pu2) OR (user1 = pu2 AND user2 = pu1) ;

    IF ROW_COUNT() = 0
    THEN -- no row has been updated, record must be created
        INSERT INTO similarities VALUE (pu1, pu2, ps) ;
    END IF ;
END ;
```

@Vatev's solution seemed attractive at first sight, but I don't think it is possible to implement the desired behaviour with triggers. This is because

1) it is impossible to turn an `UPDATE` into an `INSERT`, and vice-versa, [since](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-triggers.html):

> *[A trigger]* is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger

2) an UPDATE trigger can only access the row that is currently being modified

Comment: My suggestion is a hack to create a constraint for unique unordered pairs (a,b = b,a). It seems to work, but I haven't tested it in all possible circumstances... As for recalculating all the similarities - it can't be done only in the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a trigger on table which will check for any combination of user1 and user2 in table and if any combination exists, it updates the corresponding row.